# Wide tally dataframe to tall indicator dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

This is not a complicated problem, and I have a solution, but I can't shake the feeling that there is a better way:

I have a data.frame with a tally of successes and opportunities by category, like this:

```
testFrame <- data.frame(successes = c(100, 150, 18),
                        opportunities = c(215, 194, 40),
                        category = LETTERS[1:3])
testFrame$category <- as.character(testFrame$category)
```

I want to convert this to a "tall" data.frame, with one column of 1s and 0s indicating success/failure and a second with category labels. I can do this with the following code:

```
tallFrame <- lapply(1:nrow(testFrame), function(rr){
  cbind(rep(c(1, 0), c(testFrame[rr, "successes"], testFrame[rr, "opportunities"]-testFrame[rr, "successes"])), testFrame[rr, "category"])
  })
tallFrame <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, tallFrame))
```

The resulting `tallFrame` is a matrix which I can then convert to a data.frame without any issues, but this seems like a lot of code for a simple task. Surely there is a way to do this more code-efficiently, perhaps with `plyr` or `reshape`, or maybe I'm just looking for some code golf.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One does wonder why you need to do this, but regardless...

A `base` solution using `rep`

```
with(testFrame, data.frame(category = rep(category, opportunities), 
    indicator =  unlist(mapply(rep, times = c(successes,  opportunities-successes), 
      MoreArgs = list(x = c(0,1))))))
```

A `data.table` solution (coding elegance (perhaps a code golf competitor)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(testFrame)
DT[,list(indicator = rep(c(0,1), c(successes,  opportunities-successes))), by = category]
```

Comment: This has sent me down the path to a wonderful world of data.table. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

and here is the `plyr` solution you were looking for:

```
ddply(testFrame, .(category), function(x) {
     data.frame(raw = c(rep(1,x$success), rep(0, x$opportunities - x$success)), 
        category = x$category)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for this; helps me better understand plyr.