# Commands to transform data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm struggling with coming up with the correct process to transform some data I'm doing analysis on without resorting to a scripting language.

The data takes a format similar to the following

```
data.frame(Group=LETTERS[1:3],Total=c(100,120,130),Modified=c(12,15,32))

  Group Total Modified
1     A   100       12
2     B   120       15
3     C   130       32
```

I'd like the resulting data frame to look like

```
    +-------+----------+
    | Group | Modified |
    +-------+----------+
    | A     | Y        |
    | A     | Y        |
    | A     | Y        |
    | .     | .        |
    | .     | .        |
    | .     | .        |
    | A     | N        |
    | A     | N        |
    | B     | Y        |
    | B     | Y        |
    | .     | .        |
    | .     | .        |
    | .     | .        |
    | B     | N        |
    +-------+----------+
```

There should be 12 rows with Group A and Modified = Y and 88 rows with Group A and Modified = N. Same goes for B, C, etc.

In most cases there are additional columns that will need to be repeated on each row along with the Group info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wide tally dataframe to tall indicator dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003018/wide-tally-dataframe-to-tall-indicator-dataframe)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `rep` with the appropriate  `times` argument.

A `data.table` solution for coding elegance

```
library(data.table)
# your data is in the data.frame DF
DF <- data.table(DF)
levels <- c('Y', 'N')
DF[,list(Modified = rep(levels,c(Modified,Total-Modified))),by = Group]
```

Comment: Changed my mind. Is exact duplicate. And who better should know except you?

Comment: Yes, when  I was writing this answer, I had this thought that I'd done this before....

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is wide tally and tall indicator the correct way to refer to the two data formats?

Comment: @Garrett, it would be *a* (possibly) correct way but not the only way. Your example, the new Modified column is an indicator, but not in the regular `0 or 1` format. I would usually say `long` instead of `tall`, but that is just personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Code to convert:

```
result <- do.call(rbind,
                by(test,
                   test$Group,
                   function(x) 
                     data.frame(
                      Group=x$Group[1],
                      Modified=rep(c("Y","N"),c(x$Modified,x$Total - x$Modified))
                      )
                   )
                  )
```

Output like:

```
> head(result)
    Group Modified
A.1     A        Y
A.2     A        Y
A.3     A        Y
A.4     A        Y
A.5     A        Y
A.6     A        Y
```

Checking it worked:

```
> with(result,table(Group,Modified))
     Modified
Group   N   Y
    A  88  12
    B 105  15
    C  98  32
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
dat <- data.frame(Group=LETTERS[1:3],Total=c(100,120,130),Modified=c(12,15,32))

dat$diff <- dat$Total - dat$Modified
library(reshape2)
dat2 <- melt(dat[, -2])
dat2 <- dat2[order(dat2$Group), ]
levels(dat2$variable) <- c("Y", "N")
dat2 <- dat2[rep(1:nrow(dat2), dat2$value), -3]
rownames(dat2) <- NULL
```